# Name or symbol for this simple Laplacian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology, graph-laplacian, circulant-matrices

Is there a special name for a symbol for such Laplacian matrix?

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
-1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0\\
0& 0 & -1 & 2 & -1\\
-1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Do you mean something like: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Laplace_operator

Comment: this looks like periodic boundary condition matrix for second order differential equation